# Listado fuera del mes actual

Tags: php

Hice un script en el cual hago una consultas de deudas sobre el mes actual:

```
<?php
$date = date('F');
$cuenta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cuentas WHERE periodo = '".$date."'");

while ($row = $cuenta->fetch()){
    $estado = $row['estado'];
        if($estado == 0){
    //lista de deudas....
    }
}
?>
```

El anterior script me trae todas las deudas del mes en curso, tiene estado `0`, lo que significa que están impagadas.

En el siguiente script quiero traer una lista de deudas de los meses anteriores ya que en el código anterior me trae los del mes actual.

El problema es que me lista las deudas de todos los meses incluso el del actual y el del actual ya lo tengo arriba.

```
<?php
$cuenta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE ucode = '".$code."'");

while ($rows = $cuenta->fetch()){
    if($date != date('F')-1){

    $status = $rows['estado'];
    if($status == 0){
        echo 'Hay deudas en los meses '.$rows['periodo'];
    } else {
        echo 'No hay deuda en los meses anteriores';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Disculpa no termina de quedar claro lo que tratas de obtener con dicha consulta, tal vez pueda quedar mas claro si editas y explicas a detalle colocando un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y los datos que esperas de salida.

Comment: Gracias @Aprendiz, ahi lo modifique. Lo que trato de decir es que el primer codigo tengo una lista de deudas del mes actual y en el codigo de abajo trato de tener una listta de deudas de los meses anteriores y no logro hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo, para empezar, cambiaría la primera consulta a la siguiente:

```
<?php
/* Obtengo los registros del mes en curso que están impagados */
$date = $conn->quote(date('F'));
$cuenta = $conn->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM cuentas
    WHERE
      periodo = $date
      AND estado = 0
");

while ($row = $cuenta->fetch()) {
    /* Ya no es necesario comprobar si "estado" es 0 */
    // Lista de deudas...
}
```

He hecho uso de [`PDO::quote()`](https://php.net/es/pdo.quote) para evitar las desastrosas consecuencias de la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

De modo que la segunda consulta sería:

```
<?php
/* Obtengo los registros que están impagados que no son del mes en curso */
$date = $conn->quote(date('F'));
$cuenta = $conn->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM cuentas
    WHERE
      periodo <> $date
      AND estado = 0
");

while ($row = $cuenta->fetch()) {
    /* Ya no es necesario comprobar si "estado" es 0 */
    // Lista de deudas de otros meses...
}
```

Es decir, es exactamente la misma consulta, pero nos quedamos con los que NO cumplan la condición de mes en curso.

Si lo que quieres es obtener un listado de meses en los que el usuario tiene deudas, entonces podrías usar [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
<?php
/* Obtengo los registros que están impagados que no son del mes en curso */
$date = $conn->quote(date('F'));
$cuenta = $conn->query("
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(periodo SEPARATOR ', ') meses
    FROM cuentas
    WHERE
      periodo <> $date
      AND estado = 0
");

if ($row = $cuenta->fetch()) {
    echo 'Tienes deudas en los siguientes meses: ', $row['meses'];
} else {
    echo 'No hay deuda en los meses anteriores';
}
```

[Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dUx6jh6iwN4sMtP8p7PNFL/2).

Comment: Gracias Oscar, pero no me esta trayendo ningun dato. El periodo de meses se guarda en este formato: `date('F')`, lo cual me lista por mes por que es un periodo mensual... modifique esta linea: `SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE periodo < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), 'F') AND estado = 0` pero no tengo resultados...

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme qué tipo de dato es tu campo `periodo`? Usa `SHOW CREATE TABLE cuentas` en phpmyadmin para ver el esquema (probablemente debas darle a "+Opciones", luego marcar "Textos completos" y pulsar en "Continuar" para ver el resultado sin cortar). También puedes verlo en "Estructura".

Comment: La tabla cuentas esta definida asi: `periodo` `may`, `june`, `july`.... etc., y se guarda con la variable `$fecha = date('F');`

Comment: ¿Y el año? ¿Dónde lo almacenas? Si no almacenas el año no podrás distinguir los del año pasado de los del año en curso.

Comment: Esta en otra tabla... tuve que hacerlo asi porque habia tenia un error agrupando fechas

Comment: El problema que tienes agrupando tablas es, probablemente, no usar tipos de datos nativos de MySQL como `DATE` o `DATETIME`, ambos usan formato estándar `YYYY-MM-DD` que permite orden de fechas basado en orden alfanumérico. Te hago la edición en mi respuesta teniendo en cuenta lo que dices del contenido del campo.

Comment: Entiendo, por eso habia quitado trabajar con consultas.... declare una variable nueva asi `$mesates = date('F', strtotime('now -1 month'));` y lo que hace es traer el mes anterior

Comment: Por ahora me sirve, pero solo es el mes anterior, si hay una deuda en el mes de mayo no la puedo ver

Comment: En tu pregunta dices "meses anteriores", por eso cambié la igualdad y debería funcionar para cualquier otro mes. Por cierto, tu código fallará los meses de enero ya que diciembre estará en otra tabla.

Comment: Creo que estamos extendiendo demasiado la conversación a través de comentarios. [Deberíamos continuar el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95849/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-qodde).